# How to check for permissions from interaction in discord.js

Tags: typescript, discord.js

I need help understanding how to write this in typescript.
I tried this in javascript and it works. 
 (returns true or false whether the user who made the interaction has the administrator permission)

```
execute(client, interaction) {
    console.log(interaction.member?.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR"));
  }
```

My try in typescript:

```
execute(client: MyClient, interaction: CommandInteraction) {
    console.log(interaction.member?.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR"));
  },
```

Typescript has an error on .has:

```
Property 'has' does not exist on type 'string | Readonly<Permissions>'.
Property 'has' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [casting](https://www.typescripttutorial.net/typescript-tutorial/type-casting/) `interaction.member` as a `GuildMember`

```
// Namespace 
import { GuildMember } from "discord.js";

execute(client: MyClient, interaction: CommandInteraction) {
   const member = interaction.member as GuildMember;
   console.log(member.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR"));
},
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to [`CommandInteraction.member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/CommandInteraction?scrollTo=member) being `?GuildMember | ?APIGuildMember`. If you click the [APIGuildMember link](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#guild-member-object) you will see that permissions is type string. I’m not really familiar with TS but I think this is a solution

```
execute(client: MyClient, interaction: CommandInteraction) {
   const member = interaction.member as GuildMember
console.log(member?.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR"));
  }
```

Comment: I don’t even know if my syntax is correct. Please fix it if it’s wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! It recognises .has now! But the interaction.member can also be null and now it's giving me an error that the types don't match even when there's the '?'. `Type 'GuildMember | APIInteractionGuildMember | null' is not assignable to type 'GuildMember'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'GuildMember'.`

Comment: I am also very unfamiliar with typescript... Hence the username

Comment: The error occures because `const member: GuildMember` is stating that `member` can *only* have the shape of a GuildMember, however `interaction.member` has 3 possible types and cannot be confined to a GuildMember type

Comment: Your answer was my idea, I just didn’t know how to do it in TypeScript

Answer (score 0):

```js
//it is changed, use this:

if (interaction.memberPermissions.has('yourpermission'))
{
// your code`enter code here`
}
```